# How to integrate scrcpy window into Flutter Windows Desktop Application?

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop, flutter-windows

I want use Flutter Windows Desktop to develop a mobile phone control application.

But I do not know how to integrate scrcpy window into the Flutter Application.

I'm not familiar with C + +, can I solve this problem by using Flutter PlatfomView?

Thank you very much for you answer!